# Can an iOS app get in a state where it can't be deleted from the device?

Tags: iphone, ios

One of my users is on an iPhone 4 and said that after my game was interrupted by a phone call, she was no longer able to touch objects in the game when she returned.  Yeah, that's probably my fault.

But she also said that she tried to delete the app and re-install it but couldn't delete it.  I explained the deletion procedure, but she said she did all that, and when she tapped on the X nothing happened.

Should I believe her?

Comment: In such a case, tell her to reboot her phone, first of all...

Comment: I once had a similar experience and with iOS5, two apps i bought just won't finish installing. So it is possible that there are bugs in iOS that lead to this. Wouldn't be your fault, however.

Comment: The app lives in a "sandbox" so normally there is no problem when the app exits. But i already had a problem with older version of firmware when i used method swizzling without restore original methods before exiting the app.

Comment: Normally this shouldn't happen but iOS5 seems to have a few bugs left in it so it is possible. Tell her to try reset the phone first,then try to move the app around and then delete it if possible, or try to remove it through itunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem on iOS 4.
She just need to reboot the phone and that should be ok.

In last case, she shoud try to delete the app from her iTunes library, and into iTunes delete the app on the iPhone, then make a Sync. If on iOS 5, the problem will be that the app wil be downloaded back and back again from the phone to iTunes (expect if it's a dev version), but with iOS4, that should be fine.